# How to allow only certain words consecutively with Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, search, match

I'm trying to write a regex that will return `true` if it matches the format below, otherwise, it should return `false`. It should only allow words as below:

**Positive match** (return true)

```
UA-1234-1,UA-12345-2,UA-34578-2
```

**Negative match** (return false or null)

Note: `A` is missing after `U`

```
UA-1234-1,U-12345-2
```

It should always give me true when the string passed to regex is 
`UA-1234-1,UA-12345-2,UA-34578-2,...........`

Below is what I am trying to do but it is matching only the first element and not returning null.

```
var pattern=/^UA-[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?/g;

pattern.match("UA-1234-1,UA-12345-2,UA-34578-2");

pattern.exec("UA-1234-1,UA-12345-2,UA-34578-2)
```

Thanks in advance. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you need is a pattern enclosed with anchors (`^` - start of string and `$` - end of string) that matches your pattern at first (the initial "block") and then matches 0 or more occurrences of a `,` followed with the block pattern.

It looks like `/^BLOCK(?:,BLOCK)*$/`. You may introduce optional whitespaces in between, e.g. `/^BLOCK(?:,\s*BLOCK)*$/`.

In the end, the pattern looks like [`^UA-[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(?:,UA-[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/cf3yoW/2). It is best to build it dynamically to keep it readable and easy to maintain:

```js
const block = "UA-[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?";
let rx = new RegExp(`^${block}(?:,${block})*$`); // RegExp("^" + block + "(?:," + block + ")*$") // for non-ES6
let tests = ['UA-1234-1,UA-12345-2,UA-34578-2', 'UA-1234-1,U-12345-2'];
for (var s of tests) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

split the string by commas, and test each element instead.

Comment: This is barely an answer. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you @Calvin Taylor. Is it not possible using regex?